# Extra Classes to column in WOffice Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When using the visual editor in the Wordpress there WOffice it gives you the option to add "Extra Class to the column". underneath the text box it says "Such as: center to align in the middle the content inside." Now i have tried many other options other than "center" but nothing seems to work. please let me know where i can find these activation words to change the area of the text.

Answer (score 0):

https://woffice.io/ is using Bootstrap so you can simply use `text-center` to center any content in your column. See: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-inline-text